# React Native border right / left colors do not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, styled-components

I am using `styled-components` in React Native and the problem is that `border-left-color` and `border-right-color` fields do nothing. Border top and bottom fields function correctly. Same problem persists also when using `StyleSheet`. I am testing on Android emulator.

I have searched for solutions everywhere and I am unable to find any answer, since no one seems to be having this same problem.

Here is a simple demonstration:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
import { TextInput as NativeTextInput } from 'react-native'
import theme from '../components/theme'

const formFieldBaseStyle = css`
  background-color: ${theme.colors.appBackground};
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: ${theme.colors.borderLight}
`

const TextInput = styled(NativeTextInput).attrs({
  placeholderTextColor: theme.colors.textSecondary,
})`
  ${formFieldBaseStyles}
  color: ${theme.colors.textPrimary};
  font-size: ${theme.fontSizes.body};
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-left-color: #F00
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason `border-left-color` and `border-right-color` did not override `border-color` value, but for some reason `border-top-color` and `border-bottom-color` did. Defining all border colors individually solved the problem. This is probably a bug.

Solution:

```
const formFieldBaseStyle = css`
  background-color: ${theme.colors.appBackground};
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  /* Colors must be defined individually so they can be overridden*/
  border-left-color: ${theme.colors.borderLight};
  border-right-color: ${theme.colors.borderLight};
  border-top-color: ${theme.colors.borderLight};
  border-bottom-color: ${theme.colors.borderLight};
`
```

Answer (score 0):

For me It's working when I replaced `borderLeftColor:'red'` with
`borderStartColor:'red'` like this

```
const formFieldBaseStyle = css`
  background-color: ${theme.colors.appBackground};
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 1px;
  borderStartColor:'red';
`
```